# PHP mysqli slow loading.

Tags: php, performance, mysqli

Evening all!

I'm optimizing my website, and I'm running into some peculiar behaviour.  Before, I assumed it was because of the calculations being done on the data I was using, but I'm starting to question this.

I find that running some code like:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 55 ; $i++) { 
  $query = "SELECT id FROM gamedata_concepts WHERE game_id=12277";

  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query){
  }
}
```

Takes about 3 seconds, however, if I call that query once in say, phpMyAdmin, it says it takes '.0121' seconds, multiply that by 55 (the testing number used above in the loop), and it SHOULD take appx. .6655 seconds.  I'm curious as to maybe where this backend is?  Or better, how I can engineer this better to be more efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an index on game_id?

Comment: ...I do not. 

And don't fault me here, but I don't see why that's necessary.  
Perhaps I don't get the concept, but if phpMyadmin doesn't need it, why do I?

Comment: @Adola Are you familiar with MySQL's query-cache? I could run a 5 minute query that takes .01 seconds the second time. Just because a query executes quickly doesn't mean it's optimized. Run an EXPLAIN on your query to see if it's using a key.

Comment: @Adola it's the first thing you should do when you're trying to get the performance working. Never rely on manual query results as the OS caches, the query software caches, the database itself caches, the CPU caches, and the CPU's cache caches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not refactor your query to use IN instead of 55 queries?

```
SELECT id FROM gamedata_concepts WHERE game_id IN (12277, 12278, 12279, ...)
```

Any time you see a query being executed in a loop it's usually a bad sign.

Comment: Mike, I'm doing it that way because technically this is my code: 

http://pastebin.com/H5Gnnufs
If it's not clear, I'm just getting data based on game ids from an array, I don't know how to use IN in this case.

Comment: After re-writing my implementation to take advantage of this, I've noticed a severe speed increase.  From 3 seconds to .08

Unless I'm mistaken though, it's much harder to work with the data this way.  Because instead of having rows relevant to 'game_id', I now have to actually parse all the rows for all the game_ids.  So long as its faster.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use transactions to do this with more speed

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
for ($i=0; $i < 55 ; $i++) { 
  $query = "SELECT id FROM gamedata_concepts WHERE game_id=12277";

  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query){
  }
}
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```